# How to prevent \cite at the end of the sentence start a new line with a dot

Tags: line-breaking, citing

When I end a sentence like this:

```
Here is something you should read \cite{name}.
```

Sometimes the end of the sentence coincies with the end of a row. In this case the next line begins with the dot at the end of the sentence.

Putting the dot *before* the `\cite`

```
Here is something you should read.\cite{name}
```

solves the problem, but I checked some scientific articles and they all put the dot *after* the `\cite` and do not get this adverse effect.

How can I prevent the dot to jump to the next line?

EDIT: A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{jarticle}
\usepackage{evocomp}

\begin{document}
----------------Here is something you should read\cite{lal}.
\end{document}
```

It seems that the problem is in the `evocomp` package I am using.

Comment: `You should see \hbox{paragraph~\ref{name}.}` ?

Comment: @T.Verron This makes the dot stay where it should, but it makes the reference undefined

Comment: We will need to see a minimal working example of your input: normally the full stop (period) would not get broken in the way you describe. It's also worth noting that what you describe sound more more citations (`\cite`) than cross-references, and these may come before or after punctuation depending upon the publisher's style.

Comment: @JosephWright you are right it is \cite. I will repair it

Comment: Then `Here is something you should read \hbox{\cite{name}.}` should work (but the result may be awful, since it may push the cite on the next line as well).

Comment: @T.Verron Yes it works, thank you. It was my mistake.

Comment: Using `\hbox{paragraph~\cite{name}}` doesn't really work as it may disable hyphenation of the word paragraph. Putting the `\hbox` around the `\cite` also prevents it. In cases like this, I'd suggest rephrasing the sentence with the quotation or rewriting BibTeX or `biblatex`. (See also the last epigraph on Page 107 of the TeXBook.:-)

Comment: what's in this evocomp.sty? -- i don't see it on ctan (though perhaps it's snaffled in someone's .dtx file).  without seeing the package it's surely impossible to comment (sensibly) on the effect it has...

Comment: @wasteofspace I really appreciate your effort, but it is kind of long http://pastebin.com/RdcBavNS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you pasted in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RdcBavNS) defines the guts of `\cite` as follows:

```
\def\@cite#1#2{{$^{\mbox{\scriptsize $#1$}}$%
    \if@tempswa , #2\fi}$^{\mbox{\scriptsize $)$}}$ }
```

The last space, immediately before the final closing brace, has *got* to be a mistake. It separates the punctuation that follows, with the result that LaTeX can break the line there.

To fix the problem, *do not* edit the style in place. If you do, and submit your LaTeX source to the journal, they'll use the buggy style and your work will be for nought. (But do tell the creators of the style about the bug). What you *should* do is put the fixed version in the preamble of your document, *after* `\usepackage{evocomp}`, like this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{{$^{\mbox{\scriptsize $#1$}}$%
    \if@tempswa , #2\fi}$^{\mbox{\scriptsize $)$}}$}
\makeatother
```

Do this and you won't need to mess with `\hbox`ing your citations anymore-- they'll work as they're meant to.

Comment: Wow! That is very impressive. Also thank you for the advice on not meessing with the .sty!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inline citation in a paragraph then simply put a tilde(~) symbol with the text. For example,

```
[YOUR TEXT]~\cite{[CITATION]}.
```

If its figure or table, you can simply put full-stop in caption tag. For example,

```
\caption{[TEXT FOR YOUR FIGURE]~\cite{[CITATION]}.}
```

This will occur the citation to stick with the text.

Comment: I'm not certain that it answers the question. Adding a ``~`` will prevent the line to break between the last word of the text and the citation, but not between the citation and the dot at the end of the sentence.